# Specifiying trigonometric homework topic

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to find materials/examples for a problem that goes something like this:

You are given the function f(x)=$\frac{1}{2}$cos x. Solve the equation f(x)=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$ within range [0;2$\pi$].

My question is, what is this topic, exactly? The above problem has too little documentation in my native language so I tried translating it(poorly) and searching for cosine function/trigonometry but that doesn't seem tight enough. Could someone tell me the related topics or keywords for this problem or maybe even a source with materials, if possible?

Comment: Maybe, you will find a table in your textbook where sine/cosine values for some common angles are given. Use them to solve the equation.

Comment: Translate this equation as an equation for `\cos x`, then solve the trigonometric equation within the given range?

Comment: The topic is called trigonometric equations.

Comment: When I try searching for trigonometric equations I only find the simple ones? This should be a little bit more advanced, no?

Comment: The equation you are asked to solve in this example is literally $\frac12\cos x =\frac{1}{\sqrt8}.$ It is one of the relatively simple ones. By quick search for "trigonometric equations" I found multiple resources that deal with equations of this complexity, including http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/TrigEquations.aspx, https://academics.utep.edu/Portals/1788/CALCULUS%20MATERIAL/5_3%20SOLVING%20TRIG%20EQNS.pdf, and https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/trig-equations-and-identities-precalc.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize with how the problem is presented. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to $$\cos x=\sqrt\frac12,$$ which is true for every $$x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n,\qquad n\in\mathbb Z.$$
Since we are in the range $[0, 2\pi]$, the only solutions are $$x=\frac14\pi\lor x=\frac74\pi.$$

You can also think of $\pi/4$ as an angle. Then, take a rectangular triangle with this angle ($\pi/4=45^\circ$) and lenth $1$ of the hypotenuse. Then, the other two sides have to have length $1/\sqrt2$, which you can prove using Pythagoras theorem. Thus, you have proven the relation (because then, $\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{1/\sqrt2}{1}$ by the geometric definition of cosine).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but could you maybe add some sources I could use, to understand this problem better? I really can't do anything at all with simply an answer to this one equation since I know nothing about this topic, I'm sorry

Comment: I have edited my post and added a few more details:)